# php - converting from one json format to another

Tags: php, mysql, json

I am using php to fetch data from mysql database and json encoding the fetched output

```
json_encode($data)
```

The resultant data is in the form:

```
[
    {
        name: "aaa"
    },
    {
        name: "bbb"
    }
]
```

I want to put this into a bigger json object and output in the following format in the web browser:

```
{
    content:[
        {
            name: "aaa"
        },
        {
            name: "bbb"
        }
    ]
}
```

How do i do this using php?

Comment: Edit $data to add the extra dimension

Comment: What prevents you from doing `json_encode(array('content' => $data))`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As written in the comment you can just do `json_encode(array('content' => $data))`. You can also dynamicly create the array and just feed `json_encode` with a variable containing the whole array.